# Not able to get XP on LAN game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing on a LAN with my brother lately and it all worked fine for a while then I couldn't collect XP any more. By that I mean I can pick up the XP orbs and they make a sound and that's it, my XP bar does not go up.

1. We are both on 1.7.5 with Optifine
2. It worked for a while
3. We are playing on offline mode
4. We do have different accounts (Bought)
5. My brother's hosting and his XP works
6. Even using /xp doesn't work (E.g /xp 15L not working)
7. I have tried going on default resource pack, it's not the resource pack
8. Nothing works (E.g /xp, Killing Mobs, Mining.)
9. Problems that may be related: I can't open a chest after a while, Can't use item frames after a while, Can't see named mobs after a while, Can't use dogs after a while (This all happens after about 10 minutes of gameplay but not with XP)

Comment: Restart your game. Seems that client isn't synchronized with the server.

Comment: This is definitely a desync problem. Try restarting your client or reconnecting. If that does not work, then it might be a connection issue of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 3 things that cause this, the client, server or you.

Server: try restarting the server, synch problem!

Client: same, restart!

You: you're in such an high XP level, it looks like youre not gaining anything, but you do

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen a couple times where restarting my client did not fix it, and restarting the server did not fix it. I was not a very high level (level 57 the last time it happened), and I know how to read the experience bar (which was stuck at 0%), so it was not a mistake on my part.

I killed myself with fall damage, and that fixed the problem, although it took a little while to work my way back up to the level I was before I died. Once I did, I was able to continue gaining experience normally (until it eventually happened a second time).

This was in Minecraft 1.8.9.

I have not figured out (yet) how to reliably reproduce this issue.